# It depends on the user role to show elements in angular, how to control it?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two types of users, an administrator and a normal user, I want to hide part of the menu as a normal user

Comment: Angular has directives that you can use to conditionally show/hide UI widgets. You wire one of those into your authorizationmechanism (or create your own)

Answer (score 0):

For Angular:
in your html file:

```
<div *ngIf="user.userType !== 'normalUser'"> Your Content that you don't want to display to normal users <div>
```

in your ts file:

```
  // if you want to decide it on the initialization of component then define it in ngOnInit, like:
    
    user: User;
        
        ngOnInit() {
          this.getUser()
        }
        
        private getUser() {
          // logic for get user and assign it to user
        }
```